# How to delete constraint inside a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have read a lot about it, but being new to Postgres, I am at a loss.

The trigger is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER foopolygon
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON polygon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE maj_foo();
```

Part of the function is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maj_foo() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
     THEN

    ALTER TABLE points
    DROP CONSTRAINT bar;

    INSERT INTO points(gid,fookey)
    VALUES(0,NEW.fookey);

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE points SET fookey = ' ||  quote_literal(NEW.fookey)  || ' WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, $1)'
    USING NEW.geom;

  ALTER TABLE points
  add constraint bar
  foreign key (fookey)
  references polygon (fookey);

      COMMIT;
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'......
```

Comment: What do you mean, I am not dropping constraint?   ALTER TABLE points
    DROP CONSTRAINT bar;

Comment: It's not a good idea to drop and recreate constraints for every inserted row.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the trigger is trying to do/enforce (with sample data from the 2 tables)? Perhaps there's a more simple way.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to set your foreign key [`DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) so that you don't have to drop and recreate it every time there is an `INSERT` or other data change.  Maybe even this is not needed, but it depends on what happens in the rest of the transaction.

Then the rest is just

```
IF tg_op = 'INSERT
THEN
    INSERT INTO points (gid, fookey)
    VALUES (0, NEW.fookey);

    UPDATE points 
    SET fookey = NEW.fookey
    WHERE ST_Within(points.geom, NEW.geom);
ELSIF ...
```

**Notes:**

- you cannot `COMMIT` from inside a function
- the DB is either PostgreSQL or Postgres, *not* Postgre.
- logically, this is more an `AFTER` trigger than a `BEFORE` one.